# click on one Specific button using capybara in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, click, integration-testing, capybara

I am working with rails 3 and currently writing test with capybara using selenium driver,
I have issue as below

In one form i have 3 button named "save and add another", "save and continue editing" and "Save"
Now, if i try to save form by capybara as below

```
click_button 'Save'
```

Then this throws error called 'Save' button with id,title or value not found
Now if i remove the above 2 buttons and then i try that then it works

FYI, My 3 button's html as below,

`<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Save and add another" name="_addanother" data-disable-with="Save and add another">`

`<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Save and continue editing" name="_continue" data-disable-with="Save and continue editing">`

`<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="_save" data-disable-with="Save">`

Please let me know if anyone has an idea.

Comment: Try click_button "Save" (double quotes). Have you tried adding a distinctive id to each button and using that instead of value?

Comment: Dans, yes i have tried by adding ids to the buttons but that doesn't work

Comment: Okay, i have tried again by ids and it works Thanks, but do you know is there any reason of not working by button values ?

Comment: I think the problem is that all the values are matched as they all contain 'Save'

Comment: hmm, may be but this should not happen, thanks Dans for your answers and time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is that all the values return a match because they all contain 'Save'.

Try assigning each one a distinctive id and using that instead.

Answer (score 3):

[Matching With Exactness](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#exactness) - from the GitHub docs. Using exactness would probably make less of an impact than altering your templates.

`click_button('Save', exact: true)`

This would only find the exact match and skip the 'Save blah' action.

Comment: Prefer this answer to the accepted answer as it doesn't involve editing your markup.

Answer (score 0):

click_button methods expects id, name, value of the button.Below will work.

```
click_button 'Save and add another'
click_button 'Save and continue editing'
```

And last button works without any error because its value is 'Save'

```
click_button 'Save'
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the last one only works when the other buttons are removed...

Comment: Thanks, but yes i know that 'Save' button should work if i write `click_buttion 'Save'`, but currently it is not working and it throws error as i said in my qustion.. if i remove my above 2 buttons then only this `click_button 'Save'` works

Comment: No this is also not working.. and it throws error `no button with value or id or text 'Save' found` but anyway, i get the solution, i have added ids to those buttons and then it works fine, thanks for your answers and time

Comment: To be clear, an id, __text__ or value is expected. It will not match by __name__.

Answer (score -1):

I have come up with the following solution

module ValidUserRequestHelper

```
# for use in request specs
def sign_in_as_a_valid_user
  before(:each) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    visit user_session_path
    fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'name@email.com'
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'foobar'
    click_button 'Einloggen'
  end
end
```